# Contact form loading error debug

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to implement a contact form, taken from Reusableforms, in my site.

It works perfect in a demo page http://aprehende.pe/demo/formpage.html but when I try to make it work in my site http://aprehende.pe/demo/index.html, it just reloads and didn't send the message.

I suspect that there's a conflict with bootstrap, jquery or css. I've seen my code and I can't find any mistake.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with jQuery loading. If you open Chrome console, you will find an error message `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`.

Have verified the source code for `index.html` and found that `form.js` is loaded ahead of `jQuery.js`.

In `index.html`, change from:

```
<script src="form.js"></script>    
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

to:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="form.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you. That solved my problem. Just a noob mistake. ;)

Comment: Glad that my response helped you.